# Three ways to use css()

Tags: jquery

jQuery supports multiple ways of specifying CSS properties:

```js
// With colon:
$('p').css({marginTop: '5px'});
$('p').css({'margin-top': '5px'});
$('p').css({'marginTop': '5px'});

// With comma:
$('p').css('marginTop', '50px');
$('p').css('margin-top', '50px');

// omg
```

Does they have any advantages / disadvantages (in comparison with one another) from practical point of view?

Comment: I would recommend using `$('p').css({marginTop: '5px'});` when setting multiple properties using an object and `$('p').css('marginTop', '50px');` when setting a single property using its CSS property name. The other format are convenience alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the above are identical [behind the scene](https://api.jquery.com/css/#css2), but from a code maintenance standpoint, using `$('p').css({'margin-top': '5px'});` might be better to set a single property as it’s the required format to get a property.

`$('p').css({marginTop: '5px'});` is great when setting multiple properties.

Comment: Those both use the same syntax, just with different property names...